# Optimise currency capturing regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a regex which captures prices in the format `£10.00`, and decided that I wanted to adapt it to just `£10` as well, for example. However, the regex also matches strings in the format `£1,000.00` which is causing the problem.

This is the regex which captures `£10.00` and `£1,000.00`:

```py
pound_symbol = u'\xA3'
cost_regex = fr'(?<={pound_symbol})\d+(,\d+)*?\.\d+'
```

To change this to also allow for `£10` I though I would be able to just make the full stop optional and the digits after the full stop optional:

```py
cost_regex_fail = fr'(?<={pound_symbol})\d+(,\d+)*?\.?\d*'
```

However this didn't work because it fails to capture `£1,000` or `£1,000.00` due to the `(,\d+)*?` being lazy (the full match in these cases is `1`). As a side note it also captures `£100.` however this doesn't affect my code as I convert the string to a float directly afterwards.

I also can't switch the `(,\d+)*?` to `(,\d+)?` or `(,\d+)+?` because I can neither assume that there will be only one repeated instance of that group (`£1,000,000`) or at least one (`£10`)

Example strings which the regex should match:

`(£)100`, `(£)1,000`, `(£)1,000,000`, `(£)100.00`, `(?)1,000.00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a need for non-greedy matching (`*?`); you can simply use `*`. So this should work:

```
cost_regex = fr'(?<=£)\d+(,\d+)*(\.\d+)?'
```

https://regex101.com/r/A0em21/1